# safe to kill postgres processes with SIGTERM?

Tags: postgresql, signals, postgresql-9.2

I was debugging a PostgreSQL 9.2 database corruption issue (on Solaris, but I doubt it matters) recently, and I found that we could reproduce it reliably if the client died in the middle of a transaction and then I shut down PostgreSQL by doing `pkill postgres` (which basically sends `SIGTERM` to every running `postgres` process). If instead we did `pkill -QUIT postgres` to send `SIGQUIT`, the database would shut down cleanly and no corruption would occur.

Based on the [PostgreSQL 9.2 docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/server-shutdown.html), I think that `SIGTERM` should be 100% expected by the database server, so why is it not safe to shut down like this? Is it a bug in PostgreSQL, or could I be doing something (configuration, etc.) that would allow the corruption to occur?

Comment: (1) this is a question more suited to dba.stackexchange.com; (2) what is the exact version, 9.2.what? (3) what is the "corruption" you are talking about? What error, logs, symptoms, etc.? (4) Any non-safe option, like disabled fync or full_page_writes?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think sigterm is what is causing your problem.  Again, recommend you ask on dba.stackexchange instead.

If the client dies in the middle of a transacction, then the problem is that the network connection hangs? And then when you kill it you get corruption during WAL replay?

This is a complicated area to troubleshoot but here are some places to begin:

1. What is going on conncurrently when this happens?  What sort of transaction commit load?
2. How often do WAL logs normally get rotated?

It is possible you could be running into a rare, obscure bug with PostgreSQL (possibly somewhere between the db, kernel, and filesystem), but if so please start by upgrading to latest 9.2 and try to reproduce again.  Term and even kill signals are supposed to be 100% safe on PostgreSQL so if you are seeing database corruption, that is not expected.